# How to select images from a folder in a directory?

Tags: php

am using a slideshow similar to  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/23/fresh-sliding-thumbnails-gallery-with-jquery-php, i want each image of a folder to be displayed instead of drop down as am trying to learn PHP.....Please help

Comment: Learning things generally involves trying things before asking a question that sounds quite like "do this for me". Post what you've tried so far, and where you've run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

First: it's a really specific question. Post your code? What did you try?

However: regarding your title `"How to select images from a folder?"`, start from here:

```
<?php

$directory = '.'; // your directory

$files  = scandir( $directory );
$images = array();

foreach( $files as $file )
{
    $attributes = getimagesize( $file );
    if( $attributes )
    {
        array_push( $images, $file );
    }
}

// An array with your images
print_r( $images );
```